# How to use one same decorator on both classes and functions of class in typescrit?

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

i want to use one common decorator to decorate a function, or use the same decorate on a class,how can i distinguish two of them,just like:

```js
function decorate (params){
  if(onClass){
    return ClassDecorator
  }
  else {
    return MethodDecorator 
  }
}
```